# Calling React Hook within HoC

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I've a HoC which accepts a collection of components, and wrap them in a div which essentially makes them swippable. The code works fine in browser but jest test fails and intellisense shows warning for using useEffect

```
import React,{useEffect} from "react";

export const swiper = (components) => {
  const swiperHoc = props => {
    useEffect(()=>{console.log('HocLogged')})
    return <div>{components}</div>;
  };
  return swiperHoc;
};
```

Warning: React Hook "useEffect" is called in function which is neither a React function component or a custom React Hook function.

JestError: Test suite failed to run

```
Invariant Violation: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component. This could happen for one of the following reasons:
    1. You might have mismatching versions of React and the renderer (such as React DOM)
    2. You might be breaking the Rules of Hooks
    3. You might have more than one copy of React in the same app
    See https: / / fb.me/react-invalid-hook-call for tips about how to debug and fix this problem.
```

Is there a better way to call hook within HoC? How can I get rid of this warning.

https://codesandbox.io/s/nervous-leakey-7z6ds

Answer (score 0):

Since they are out, hooks have two main conventions, checked by their linter plugin to be sure these rules are respected.

1) you cannot call hooks inside conditions. Not my words, think about it that "you love hooks unconditionally". This is because React relies on the order of the hook calls.

2) you can call hooks only inside custom functions starting with use word (and top level inside components of course). This is a way they need to make lint running against only custom hooks, plus a way to make a person reading the code to understand that the function called inside some component, inside uses some hook (state, etc).

In your case, rename the function into useSwiperHoc and I would also rename the hoc itself into useSwiper.

Comment: Thanks for the inputs. I got a naming cue from your response and had it working. However, I made it work with 2 corrections - 1) replaced component names to Pascal case (swiper to Swiper and swiperHoc to Swiper Hoc .  2) From jest I used ```render(<component/>)``` instead of ```render({component})```